# Show an image from ios module in titanium appcelerator

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-modules

I am able to understand the concept of View a little bit in titanium. But i donot understand how image can be wrap up as an object in titanium module and send it as an object. I just want to show a simple image in titanium which i took from server in ios module.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to simply create an ImageView which is an object.  That object will hold the image data.

Then to display the image, just add it to whatever view is on your screen:

```
var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image:'http://www.someserver.com/yourimageurl.jpg',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    top:0,
    hires: true
});

YourView.add(image);
```